# AppML Tutorial, Model Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, web

I am learning how to use AppML: http://www.w3schools.com/appml/appml_howto.asp

I have followed the instructions and created a "Customers.xml" file in directory "Models" inside of the folder containing my HTML page and the AppML files.

Here is the relevant section of the HTML page:

```
<script src="appml.js"></script>
<script>
app=new AppML("appml.php","Models/Customers.xml");
app.run("Place01","Template01");
</script>
```

When I load my HTML page, I get the response "Model required: Models/Customers.xml".

Solution?

Thank you, Jonathan

Comment: Do you have exactly the same code and files that the relevent tutorial ?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the .zip for PHP from the download page: http://www.w3schools.com/appml/appml_download.asp And I added a "Models" directory, which contains the "Customers.xml" file.